# How to pronounce -다 in dictionary form?

Tags: pronunciation, verb-endings

From what I've learnt, ㄷ is pronounced /t/ at the start of a word or end of a syllable, and /d/ if it's at the start of a syllable. So I am a bit confused as to why the -다 at the end of some verbs (in dictionary form) are not pronounced as /da/.

Examples:

- [살다](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/ef6059be902d4d35877ebca2c259919b) (to live) is pronounced [살ː다] - this is what I expect
- [좋다](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/6cbf564655854b4d8225477320c63e7a) (to be good) is pronounced [조ː타] - ㄷ is pronounced as /t/
- [먹다](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/137da569c4b8481eb07506f5ce880aac) (to eat) is pronounced [먹따] - ㄷ is pronounced as /t͈/ (but still somehow sounds like /d/)

Is there a way to know, without checking the dictionary each time, how -다 should be pronounced based on the word stem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pronunciations of the standard Korean words are [quite *predictable*](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/5571/korean-words-whose-pronunciation-differs-unpredictably-from-the-spelling) because there are the [standard (official) pronunciation rules](http://kornorms.korean.go.kr/regltn/regltnView.do;jsessionid=6BB793CA56FED9026E69289D18DBC20E?regltn_code=0002#a346). The rules are written in Korean, so you can refer to the ***second** sheet* of [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nO6-UNbYKbtku_UtRm-1MUUDA2QXzeIuMc3VsNnYamM) instead, at the moment. The list indicates where consonants and vowels shift; *however*, you should note that some conditions have *exceptions*, which you may regard as *unpredictable* ones.

Fortunately, your examples have all predictable pronunciations.

- 살다 has the ㄹㄷ (ᆯᄃ) sequence. The stem and ending of 살다 are 살 and 다, respectively, which means that the consonant ㄷ does not change when it is pronounced. As a side note, most people do not care about [the symbol ː](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_length) these days. Thus, the pronunciation of 살다 is just 살다 or 살ː다 (The latter is standard).
- 좋다 has the ㅎㄷ (ᇂᄃ) sequence. This sequence always becomes ㅌ when it is read. Therefore, 좋다 is pronounced as 조ː타 (or, more practically, 조타). If you learn more about the ㅎ sound, such a change will make sense.
- 먹다 has the ㄱㄷ (ᆨᄃ) sequence, which applies to the condition "ᄃ (following ᆨ, ᆩ, ᆪ, ᆰ, ᆿ, ᆮ, ᆺ, ᆻ, ᆽ, ᆾ, ᇀ, ᆸ, ᇁ, ᆲ, ᆵ, or ᆹ)." Then, 다 must change into 따 when it is pronounced.

Comment: I was aware of some rules related to nasal sounds (e.g. ㅂ+ㄹ ⟶ ㅁ+ㄴ, ㄱ ㅋ ㄲ+ㄹ ⟶ ㅇ+ㄴ) but not aware of the ones involving ㄷ. I also didn't know the existence of the [kornorms](http://kornorms.korean.go.kr/main/main.do) website - it will be very useful for me further in my studies (when I can read more Korean words). So thank you for you answer, it helps a lot.